# Permission Denied error when building PageSpeed from source

Tags: python, pagespeed

After running the command command

```
gclient config http://modpagespeed.googlecode.com/svn/branches/latest-beta/src
gclient sync --force --jobs=1
```

After 95%, it throws the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Error: Command /usr/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium -Dchromium_revision=256281 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/utkarsh/mod_pagespeed
```

Comment: Have you tried running with elevated privileges (sudo)?

Comment: I am installing it from source.here is the the reference to the commands to follow.https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_mod_pagespeed_from_source?hl=de here,they have not asked to run command with sudo privileges

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Have you tried running the command with sudo permissions?

Comment: I tried but it is showing:"sudo: gclient: command not found"

Comment: Actually,it doesn't need sudo privileges

Comment: Run this command: `sudo \`which gclient\` sync --force --jobs=1`

Comment: At the start,it gives running depot tools as root is sad, but its running,lets see

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command as root user, it might give you a mean warning but it should work.

```
sudo `which gclient` sync --force --jobs=1
```

The `which gclient` is required because the $PATH for the root user sometimes doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`.